# Match multiple values in a regex string

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture one or more variables in a string, not just the first value found.  I created a test regex

```
color.*?(?<COLOR>(red|blue|black)).*?.
```

and test sentence

```
favorite colors are red, blue and black.  Mr. Green
```

which can be seen here  http://regex101.com/r/vV7bP3/2

My goal is to get a match for each of red, blue an black AND not for Green which comes after the period. In other words looking for a match for all colors in a sentence with the word 'color' but only up to the next period (I understand this is a two-part question I thought it was easier than posting twice.

Answer (score 7):

To find several colors between the word color and a dot, you can use this pattern in a global search (compatible PHP/PCRE, Perl, Ruby 2.0, Java, .NET):

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\bcolors?\b)[^.]+?\b(?<colors>red|bl(?:ue|ack))\b
```

The idea is to use the `\G` anchor that matches the end of the last match result. This technic use two entry points at the begining of the pattern (in the non-capturing group).

The first match result uses the word "color" as entry point for the pattern, and the next match results use the entry point with the `\G` anchor.

Since `[^.]` is the only character class used, you can't obtain other results after the dot. *(Note that this can cause problems with abbreviations like `Mr.` or acronyms like `U.S.A.`)*

Note: You can reduce the work for the regex engine, by adding `.*?` before "color" (this avoids to test all the characters before "color" one by one with the 2 entry points):

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|.*?\bcolors?\b)[^.]+?\b(?<colors>red|bl(?:ue|ack))\b
```

or you can move the word boundary at the begining to fail faster *(since each match ends with a word boundary)*:

```
\b(?:\G(?!\A)|colors?\b)[^.]+?\b(?<colors>red|bl(?:ue|ack))\b
```

Comment: You can always count on Casimir's expert solutions for these problems. +1 Just wondering need of `(?!\A)` here.

Comment: @anubhava That's to prevent to have a positive match on the beginning of string.

Comment: Oh got it so `\G` succeeds even if there was no previous match.

Comment: @anubhava: exactly, at the first try, since there is not yet results, `\G` matches the start of the string.

Comment: Thanks so much that's an eye opener for me. Somehow I had this impression that `\G` won't succeed if there was no previous match.

Comment: Hi, I am trying these (all three) with my original test phrase and I keep getting 'Red' only. I'm trying to return Match 1: Color: Red, Match 2: Color: Blue, Match 3: Color: Black. That doesn't seem to happen with any of the above unless I'm reading wrong.  http://regex101.com/r/wP0yW9/1

Comment: @user3649739: with regex101 you must add a "g" modifier to obtain a global match.

Comment: Oh I see ok that worked: http://regex101.com/r/wP0yW9/2  The question then is will this work as 'standalone' inside php code? I see the g modifier is part of the regex string just not sure if regex101 requires it to be 'enabled' as its own quirk but it will work without further modification when called by Regex. Thanks

Comment: @user3649739: to be clear, the g modifier doesn't exist in PHP. To do a global search you only need to use a function that does a global search (all `preg_` functions by default, except `preg_match`)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to capture the colors which are just before to the literal `.`,

```
color[^\.]*(red|blue|black|Green)[^\.]*(red|blue|black|Green)[^\.]*(red|blue|black|Green)[^\.]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV7bP3/3)

Comment: Thanks, in fact though the array of colors will be larger and that will get unwieldy. I thought there was a way to indicate multiple matches.